# Error en condicional arrow function - no valida condicional booleano

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6

En la primera función la validación de edad del objeto la hace correctamente, pero la segunda función no genera correctamente la validación (toma el valor como false independientemente de si se cambia entre `true` o `false` en el objeto). ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
let persona = {
  nombre: "Pepito",
  apellido: "Perez",
  edad: 27,
  ingeniero: true,
  doctorado: false
}

const mayorEdad = e => e.edad < 18 ? console.log("Es menor de edad") : console.log("Es mayor de edad");
mayorEdad(persona);

const grado = ({
  ingeniero
}) => ({
  ingeniero
}) == true ? console.log("Es graduado") : console.log("No es graduado");
grado(persona);
```

Comment: Mil disculpas, ya quedó como texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces la deestructuración, es decir:

```
({ingeniero}) =>
```

Ya estas asignando la variable `ingeniero`. En la comparación:

```
({ingeniero}) == true
```

Estás cometiendo un error porque no estás comparando la variable, si no que estás usando alguna clase de objeto(`{}`) con  con la variable `ingeniero` dentro. Necesitas hacer:

```
ingeniero === true ?
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estás invocando mal el parámetro, invocalo de esta forma:

```js
let persona ={
    nombre:"Pepito",
    apellido:"Perez",
    edad:27,
    ingeniero:true,
    doctorado:false
}

const mayorEdad = e => e.edad<18 ? console.log("Es menor de edad") : console.log("Es mayor de edad");
mayorEdad(persona);

const grado = ({ingeniero})=>{
  ingeniero ? console.log("Es graduado."):console.log("No es graduado.")
}
grado(persona);
```

Esta podría ser otra forma similar

```js
let persona ={
    nombre:"Pepito",
    apellido:"Perez",
    edad:11,
    ingeniero:true,
    doctorado:false
}

//const mayorEdad = e => e.edad<18 ? console.log("Es menor de edad") : console.log("Es mayor de edad");

const mayorEdad = (e)=>{
  if(e.edad>=18){
    console.log("Mayor de edad.")
  }else{
    console.log("Menor de edad.")
  }
}
const grado = (a)=>{
  let ing = a.ingeniero
  if(ing){
    console.log("Es graduado.")
  }else{
    console.log("No es graduado.")
  }
}

mayorEdad(persona);
grado(persona)
```

Comment: Gracias! No había caído en cuenta que había podido quitar el  * == true * para validar la variable ingeniero.

Answer (score 0):

haces mal la asociación de la segunda arrow function:

```
    let persona ={
        nombre:"Pepito",
        apellido:"Perez",
        edad:27,
        ingeniero:true,
        doctorado:false
    }
    //(e) estás pasando el objeto persona y lo renombras a e
    const mayorEdad = (e) => e.edad<18 ? console.log("Es menor de edad") : console.log("Es mayor de edad");
    mayorEdad(persona);
    
//aqui a la variable algo recibe el objeto persona y puedes acceder después a su atributo ingeniero
    const grado = (algo)=>{
      algo.ingeniero ? console.log("Es graduado."):console.log("No es graduado.")
    }
    grado(persona);
```